# наследование метода для разных типов extended классов

Tags: php, ооп

Можно ли как то создать в порождающем классе `A` метод который будет применяться в расширенных классах? Если в них к примеру будут разные свойства. Как для примера ниже, просто просуммировать сумму заданных свойств

```
class A
{
    public function __construct(){}
}

class new_B extends A {   
    public $one = 1;
    public $two = 2;
    public $three = 3;
    public $four = 4;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    } 
}
class new_C extends A {   
    public $one = 1;
    public $two = 2;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, конечно, можно. Например, один из вариантов реализации

```
<?php
abstract class A
{
    public function __construct() {}

    abstract protected function listOfValues();

    public function sum() {
        return array_sum($this->listOfValues());
    }
}

class new_B extends A {
    public $one = 1;
    public $two = 2;
    public $three = 3;
    public $four = 4;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function listOfValues() {
        return array(
            $this->one,
            $this->two,
            $this->three,
            $this->four
        );
    }
}
class new_C extends A {
    public $one = 1;
    public $two = 2;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    protected function listOfValues() {
        return array(
            $this->one,
            $this->two
        );
    }
}

$b = new new_B();
echo $b->sum();
echo '<br />';
$c = new new_C();
echo $c->sum();
```

Comment: Для наглядности - http://ideone.com/b3Eccn

Comment: если есть `abstract protected function listOfValues();` то данный метод обязан быть в дочерном классе, который в принципе там и так есть. или какой еще смысл данного метода в родителе A

Comment: Можно убрать, но абстрактный класс не даст вам забыть его в новых классах-наследниках. В таком небольшом примере все очевидно, но в системе из сотни классов назначение классов и методов абстрактными может здорово облегчить отладку и сопровождение системы.

Comment: спасибо, Вы очень помогли)